# Apollo | How to Notify Subscription From Server?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, graphql-subscriptions

How do I notify the subscribed clients of the new change of the database (Mongodb) from Node.js App ?
I know it works when a client commit a mutation, but is there a way to do it on the server?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for the [Apollo Subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/): "*To generate events in the example, we notified the pubsub implementation inside of our Mutation resolver with publish. This publish call can occur outside of a resolver if required.*"

So every time your server code needs to publish updates to the client, it should call the publish() method:

```
pubsub.publish(POST_ADDED, { postAdded: args });
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you ! I want sometime notify the changes from another server .Do I have to create new API or Use the Apollo client on Node.js server

Comment: If it is another server, then you will need new API - and use publish() there.